# Changing the data in a specific area of a window, Caliburn.Micro, WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

Here is my need.  I think a user control is what I need but I am not sure if its the best or even how to use it.

What I have.  My main window has a menu with a "help" menu.  When you click help, a new window opens, I have a column, At the top of the left column has a drop down box of "Major Titles", a ListBox below that that populates based on the combo box selection. This will be about 25% of the window width.  All this works.

When I select an item in the list box a page,contentControl or user control is displayed to the right with verticle scroll bars so the window does not need to resize, the information I display that changes based on the list box selection will have only visuals like text block, label, images.  There will be no user interaction with the changeable pages Just formatted Data.

What would be the best way to approach this?  Can anyone offer an easy example?

I was thinking of using a user control and change the user control based on the selected list box item.

Comment: Could you draw a small mock-up? It would be helpful...

Comment: Sorry @arcticwhite, got side tracked. I am paying what I did to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this figured. After reading a lot of posts and blogs. Seems people sometimes want to make things more complicated then they actually are.

What I wanted, a permanent list box on the left 1/6 of the window. The list box contained string names for "help subjects". On the right 5/6 of the screen I added a groupbox with header and in group box I added a usercontrol. The content of the control is bound to a property called 'ActiveView'. The list box selected value property is bound to 'SelectedListItem' property.

When you change it set 'SelectedListItem' a method is called 'SetActiveControl'.  SetActiveControl has a switch/case that sets like in the example:

```
``Case "Setup":
             ActiveView = new       SomeSelectionViewModel();
             Break;
```

I have created a user control in a folder inside the Views folder called HelpControls, I also created the same folder in ViewModels. I have classes matching the user controls and everything is bound together.

Ultimately when you click the list box item, the associated ViewModel is called and in turn populates the user control on the window with the appropriate data.

I need to later look into, using one ViewModel for all the controls, I know that can be done using Cal:Model.View = ViewModel name. In the xaml of the control.  I'm just not sure how to call the appropriate user control view when an item is selected.  Either way this would become a view first design and I thought I read, Caliburn. Micro was intended as a ViewModel first design.